# How to insert an SVG image (icon) in the navigation bar of a Quarto file?

Tags: html, r, yaml, navbar, quarto

I'm attempting to display an SVG icon in the navigation bar using Quarto, but I'm having trouble making it work. My current code in the _quarto.yml file is as follows:

```
navbar:
...
right:
  - icon: github
    href: https://github.com/
  - icon: linkedin
    href: https://linkedin.com/
  - icon: static/img/flag-usa.svg
    href: content/experience/index.qmd
```

However, the SVG icon is not being displayed as expected. Is there a correct way to insert an SVG image into the navigation bar using Quarto? What's wrong?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to troubleshoot this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you can add local SVG file to navbar. The only option I know is [fontwesome](https://github.com/quarto-ext/fontawesome) extension. With it it should be possible to use something like `- text: "{{< fa flag-usa >}}"` instead of `-icon:` entry.

Comment: In relation to the answer provided by @GrzegorzSapijaszko check out  https://quarto.org/docs/websites/website-navigation.html where it mentions in relation to icon "Name of one of the standard Bootstrap 5 icons (e.g. “github”, “twitter”, “share”, etc.)." so static/img/flag-usa.svg will not work.

Comment: Also checkout https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/ where you can find other alternatives to Font Awesome where you can include more icons from other sites like Academicons, Iconify or Lordicon using the solution provided by @GrzegorzSapijaszko

Comment: Finally I know you need a solution now and quick as possible in stackoverflow but maybe you can ask for this feature request here https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/categories/feature-requests in relation to add an icon locally or ask the quarto community for help here https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/categories/q-a

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko Iconify has the icon I need and I didn't see that.
thanks a lot!